# MongoDB Native Query vs C# LINQ Performance

Tags: performance, linq, mongodb

I am using the following two options, the Mongo C# driver seems to be taking more time.  I'm using StopWatch to calculate the timings.

**Case 1: Native Mongo QueryDocument (takes 0.0011 ms to return data)**

```
string querytext = @"{schemas:{$elemMatch:{name: " + n + ",code : " + c + "} }},{schemas:{$elemMatch:{code :" + c1 + "}}}";
string printQueryname = "Query: " + querytext;
BsonDocument query1 = MongoDB.Bson.Serialization.BsonSerializer.Deserialize<BsonDocument>(querytext);
QueryDocument queryDoc1 = new QueryDocument(query1);
var queryResponse = collection.FindAs<BsonDocument>(queryDoc1);
```

**Case 2: Mongo C# Driver (takes more than 3.2 ms to return data)**

```
Schema _result = new Schema();
_result = (from c in _coll.AsQueryable<Schema>()
           where c.schemas.Any(s => s.code.Equals(c) && s.name.Equals(n) ) &&
                 c.schemas.Any(s => s.code.Equals(c1))
           select c).FirstOrDefault();
```

Any thoughts ? Anything wrong here ?

Comment: @JohnnyHK I forgot to add the line here.

Comment: It's still not equivalent as you need to get the first doc from the returned cursor in case 1.

Comment: @JohnnyHK Can you be more specific? Assume that I have a working code for Case 1, is there any specific reason in such difference? Is it because the C# API takes time in building expression trees, serialization etc., ?

Comment: Call `FirstOrDefault()` on `queryReponse` to make the two cases equivalent in functionality so you get an accurate timing comparison. LINQ queries are typically very efficient.